# Reading delim files in R

Tags: r, import

I have downloaded a illumina annotation file(text) from ilumina website. When I want to read it throws me an error:

```
[Error in data[[rowvar]] : attempt to select less than one element][1]
```

Here is the code what I've used:

```
annotation=read.delim("MouseWG-6_V2_R3.txt", row.names="Array_Address_Id", dec=",")
```

Please do anyone help me.

[Here is link to the text file](http://www.switchtoi.com/annotationfiles.ilmn)

Comment: Most people here won't even know what Illumina is let alone know what an annotation file is. So it would help if you showed the first few lines of the file or gave us a URL where we could take a look at the file. Otherwise how can we help if we don't know what the file looks like?

Comment: @Gavin Simpson :Sorry for the inconvenience.i have re-edited the post with screen shot and link to download the file.My apologies.

Comment: Well the screenshot hasn't worked - the figure is missing online. We don't need to see what the R console looked like - the error message you gave was fine. It was the file we needed to see. I've downloaded what I think is the one you used and will take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read that file with the standard R functions `read.delim()` and `read.table()` as it isn't in a spreadsheet-like format - i.e. it isn't plain tabular data delimited by a delimiter.

The file contains a header:

```
? Illumina, Inc.
[Heading]
Date    7/1/2010
ContentVersion  2.0
FormatVersion   1.0.0
Number of Probes    45281
Number of Controls  974
[Probes]
```

Which we could skip, but then there is another section afer the `[Probes]` section that looks like this:

```
[Controls]
Probe_Id    Array_Address_Id    Reporter_Group_Name Reporter_Group_id   Reporter_Composite_map  Probe_Sequence
ILMN_1380403    005860278   negative    permuted_negative       GCGTATTGGCTGCTGGTCTTGACCAGTGCCGGAATTCCGCTCTGATATAG
ILMN_1379274    000610201   negative    permuted_negative       TGAATGAGAACTCTTGGCCCCGGCTCCTTTCACAAAGACGGTTAGCTTGG
ILMN_1379161    004670735   negative    permuted_negative       GGAGGCATGCCACCTCTTCCTACGAACAAGTCAGGAAACGGTTCGAAGCC
ILMN_1379177    003400438   negative    permuted_negative       TTCCAATTGGCACCAAGTCATACTCCCAGTCACAGGCTAGATCTCCCGAC
ILMN_1379049    000730154   negative    permuted_negative       GGAGGCTTTCCTGCTGTGCAGGCTGTTATCAAGGGATGCTGTATCTCGGG
```

and an further section:

```
[Columns]
Name    Level   Visible
Species all 
Source  all 
Search_Key  all 
Transcript  probe   
ILMN_Gene   all 
Source_Reference_ID probe   
RefSeq_ID   probe   
Unigene_ID  all 
Entrez_Gene_ID  all 
GI  probe   
Accession   probe   
Symbol  all 
Protein_Product probe   
Probe_Id    probe   
Array_Address_Id    probe   
Probe_Type  probe   
Probe_Start probe   
Probe_Sequence  probe   
Chromosome  all 
Probe_Chr_Orientation   all 
Probe_Coordinates   probe   
Definition  all 
Ontology_Component  all 
Ontology_Process    all 
Ontology_Function   all 
Synonyms    all
```

Even the `Probes` section doesn't look that well formatted - there are huge chunks of text which might cause problems if they contain delimiters as the text is un-quoted.

If you can pull out just the `Probes` section then into a file `"filename.txt"`

```
read.table("filename.txt", sep = "\t")
```

looks like it might read the file as that section at least is tab-delimited.

Comment: :I tried by deleting the unwanted  comments line and it worked for me.thanks for timely help.I also need one more help..I have list of text files in which every file contains 3 columns(ProbeID,AVG_Signal,Detection_Pvalue).I want to verify whether do ProbeID column between the files match or not..But i m bit confused and got stuck up..can u help me?pls    .

Comment: @Thileepan Ask a new question. Comments are really for minor follow-ups.